# How to set a countdown on the button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a `Button` that, after pressing, should start a count down and would show the count down on the button.

How can I proceed?

Comment: The countdown should be managed by a timer: the pressure is only the beginning, once started, you must decrease every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
public class CountDown extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btn;
    int i=0, second = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while( i != second ) {
                        try {
                            handle.sendMessage( handle.obtainMessage());
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch( Throwable t) {

                        }   
                    }
                }  

                Handler handle = new Handler() {
                    public void handleMessage( Message msg) {
                        btn.setText( ""+ second );
                        second--;
                    }           
                };
        }).start();   

    }
}
```

Comment: If your requirement satisfies then please verify this by clicking the check button.

Comment: There is already a `CountDownTimer` offered with the android api. Have you seen it before?

Answer (score 3):

The following code will achieve what you are asking very simply. Now this is very very simple. You will need to implement `onFinish()` and possibly implement `onTick()` a little more. But this is the least amount of code to accomplish what you are wanting easily.

What you are wanting to do is use the [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) provided with the android api.

```
private long countDown = 3000;

private long interval = 1000;

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    this.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(this.countDown, this.interval) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            colorButton.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    this.colorButton.setText(Long.toString(this.countDown/1000));
    this.colorButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The countdown should be managed by a timer: the pressure is only the beginning, once started, you must decrease every second.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. This should be what you are looking for.